# How to change x-axis layout using plotly in r

Tags: r, r-plotly

I'm trying to customise the x-axis. I currently have the "Site" variable on the x-axis. The range is from 15 to 24 with site a and b for each number i.e. for 15, there is 15a and b (and so on to 24). When I label all bars, it looks messy and I'm trying to customise it so for example, the number 15 is below but the individual bars are labelled a and b. This way, the individual bars will be identifiable but it won't look so crowded.
[image: Barplot currently]

Here is my code so far:

```
#Stacked bar chart exp2 
BarChartData2 <- read.csv("Bar chart data exp 2.csv")
Site <- BarChartData2[,4]
Card <- BarChartData2[,2]
Pen <- BarChartData2[,3]
data2 <- data.frame(Site, Card, Pen)
pstacked2 <- plot_ly(data2, x = ~Site, y = ~Card, type = 'bar', name = 'Card', marker = list(color = 'Black')) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Pen, name = 'Pen', marker = list(color = 'red')) %>%
 layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Number of Bee Visits'), barmode = 'stack',  font = list(family = 'Times New Roman', size =14, color ="black"), xaxis = list(autotick = F, dtick = 2))
pstacked2
```

Any help/other ideas of how to do this will be much appreciated!

Comment: As it is we cannot run your code. You can add an example of your dataset using `dput()`.

Comment: > dput(BarChartData2[,4])
structure(1:20, .Label = c("15a", "15b", "16a", "16b", "17a", 
"17b", "18a", "18b", "19a", "19b", "20a", "20b", "21a", "21b", 
"22a", "22b", "23a", "23b", "24a", "24b"), class = "factor")    > dput(BarChartData2[,2])
c(15L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L)    > dput(BarChartData2[,3])
c(10L, 8L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 14L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 16L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 
4L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 5L)

Comment: Please put all code and information into the question itself. You can edit your question by clicking the `edit` button under the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to help you. You can play with `shapes` and `annotations` to get exatly what you want.

```
plot_ly(data2, x = ~Site, y = ~Card, type = 'bar', name = 'Card', marker = list(color = 'Black')) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Pen, name = 'Pen', marker = list(color = 'red')) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Number of Bee Visits'), 
         barmode = 'stack',  
         font = list(family = 'Times New Roman', size =14, color ="black"), 
         xaxis = list(autotick = F, dtick = 2),
         margin = list(
           r = 10, 
           t = 25, 
           b = 100, 
           l = 110
         ),
         shapes = list(
           list(
             line = list(
               color = "rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.5)", 
               width = 1
             ), 
             type = "line", 
             x0 = 0, 
             x1 = 1, 
             xref = "paper", 
             y0 = -0.05, 
             y1 = -0.05, 
             yref = "paper"
           )
         ),
         annotations = list(
           list(
             x = 0.04, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "15", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ), 
           list(
             x = 0.14, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "16", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ), 
           list(
             x = 0.24, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "17", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ), 
           list(
             x = .35, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "18", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ),
           list(
             x = .45, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "19", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ),
           list(
             x = .55, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "20", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ),
           list(
             x = .65, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "21", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ),
           list(
             x = .75, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "22", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ),
           list(
             x = .85, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "23", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           ),
           list(
             x = .95, 
             y = -0.1, 
             showarrow = FALSE, 
             text = "24", 
             xref = "paper", 
             yref = "paper"
           )
         )
         )
```

[image]