# multi-level x axis in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I didn't find any information if multiple level x axis are available for plotly. I guess it is possible to do it in ggplot2 (eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables) SO thread) and then transform it with `ggplotly()` but I would prefer a plotly solution. Is this possible? At the moment I am using an auxiliary column which concatenates year and month to the format "2017-12".

Example dataset:

```
data.frame(
        year = c(2017, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2018),
       month = c(12, 1, 2, 12, 1, 2),
       value = c(120, 110, 130, 90, 100, 110)
)
```

The result should look like this (year and month on the x axis):

[image]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with plotly, so I can't try an answer here; but, have you tried making a new variable with a line break in it?, e.g., `dataframe$label <- paste(dataframe$month, "\n", dataframe$year)` and using that for the label?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955803/how-to-change-x-axis-layout-using-plotly-in-r/51964142#51964142 could help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your x-axis values are just new line separated values you could `paste` the two columns and separate them with a HTML line break `<br />`. The labels are assigned to x-xaxis ticks.

```
library('plotly')

df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2017, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2018),
  month = c(12, 1, 2, 12, 1, 2),
  value = c(120, 110, 130, 90, 100, 110)
)

xaxis <- list('tickvals'= seq(1, length(df$year)),
              'ticktext' = paste(df$month, df$year, sep='<br />'),
              'tickmode' = 'array')

plot_ly(y=df$value, x=seq(1, length(df$year)), mode='lines', type='scatter') %>% layout(xaxis = xaxis)
```

[image]

Comment: can you help there too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443673/one-zeroline-for-two-y-axis-in-plotly - thank you for looking into it in advance :)