# One zeroline for two y axis in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

[image]

This graph is generated with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
      DEP = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
      , VALUE = c(100, 110, 120)
      , LINE = c(-0.1, 0.7, 0.9)
    )

xAxis <- list(
  title = ""
  , tickangle = 0
  , tickfont = list(size = 10)
)

yAxis <- list(
  side = "left"
  , showgrid = TRUE
  , zeroline = TRUE
  , title = ""
)

yAxis2 <- list(
  side = "right"
  , autotick = FALSE
  , ticks = "outside"
  , tick0 = 0
  , dtick = 0.1
  , showgrid = TRUE
  , zeroline = TRUE
  , overlaying = "y"
)

plot_ly(data = df, x = ~DEP) %>%
  add_trace(data = df, x = ~DEP, y = ~VALUE, name = 'VALUE', type = "bar", yaxis = "y", textposition = "auto") %>%
  add_trace(data = df, x = ~DEP, y = ~LINE, name = 'LINE', mode = "lines", type = "scatter",
            line = list(width = 4), yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(
    margin = list(r=50, b = 150)
    , xaxis = xAxis
    , yaxis = yAxis
    , yaxis2 = yAxis2
    , showlegend = FALSE
  )
```

> I would like to change the graph so that the zeroline of the left y
>   axis is shifted to the zeroline of the right y axis. Consequently the
>   bars should be shifted too:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the bars to start at 0 or the lower limit of your line/scatter chart?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I added another picture to illustrate my goal. Hope this helps to illustrate my objective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of directly doing it in Plotly. But you could set the [`range`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-range) for both axes manually.

For your bars add the following line to its layout:

```
range = c(max(df$VALUE) / max(df$LINE) * min(df$LINE), max(df$VALUE))
```

and for your lines:

```
range = c(min(df$LINE), max(df$LINE))
```

which would give the followin graph.
[image]

An easier approach would be to set the lower limit to 0 which truncates the line graph.

In the code below an additional variable `axis_buffer` was added to avoid that the range is exactly the lower and upper limit of your values.

For the sake of visual clarity I would remove some of the grid lines or try normalizing your data and adding the raw data to your hover info.

```
library('plotly')
df <- data.frame(
  DEP = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
  , VALUE = c(100, 110, 120)
  , LINE = c(-0.1, 0.7, 0.9)
)

axis_buffer <- 1.1

xAxis <- list(
  title = ""
  , tickangle = 0
  , tickfont = list(size = 10)
)

yAxis <- list(
  side = "left"
  , showgrid = TRUE
  , zeroline = TRUE
  , title = ""
  , range = c(max(df$VALUE) / max(df$LINE) * min(df$LINE) * axis_buffer, max(df$VALUE) * axis_buffer)
)

yAxis2 <- list(
  side = "right"
  , autotick = FALSE
  , ticks = "outside"
  , tick0 = 0
  , dtick = 0.1
  , showgrid = TRUE
  , zeroline = TRUE
  , overlaying = "y"
  , range = c(min(df$LINE) * axis_buffer, max(df$LINE) * axis_buffer)
)

plot_ly(data = df, x = ~DEP) %>%
  add_trace(data = df, x = ~DEP, y = ~VALUE, name = 'VALUE', type = "bar", yaxis = "y", textposition = "auto") %>%
  add_trace(data = df, x = ~DEP, y = ~LINE, name = 'LINE', mode = "lines", type = "scatter",
            line = list(width = 4), yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(
    margin = list(r=50, b = 150)
    , xaxis = xAxis
    , yaxis = yAxis
    , yaxis2 = yAxis2
    , showlegend = FALSE
  )
```